# What is the difference between edonet and edo2net?

Tags: protocol, testnet

The block explorer tzkt.io has both a `edonet` and an `edo2net` option. Are these two different blockchains and what is the difference between these two test nets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edonet should be dead as that protocol was not chosen. I imagine tzkt simply has not shut it down yet. Edo2Net should be the current testnet.